# Macro not working, empty cells in range are now 0

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will remove blanks, sort them, and convert any number less than 1000000 to text.

I'm able to get them to remove blanks, but I'm not able to change the numbers to text.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Promo1()
    Worksheets("PROMO#1").Range("A:A").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    Range("A:R").Sort key1:=Range("A:A"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("O:O"), order2:=xlAscending

    Dim productcode As Range
    Dim cells As Range

    Set productcode = Range("A1:A1000")

    For Each cells In productcode
        If cells.Value < 999999 Then
            cells.Value = CDec(cells)
        Else
        End If
    Next cells
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to change the numbers to text"? Do you mean the *format*?

Comment: Don't you want <1000000  ?

Comment: Yeah I wouldnt want the numbers in the range to be picked up by a VLOOKUP in a different sheet.

Comment: As for <10000000, anything less than that would be considered generic. I only want 1000000 and up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to change numbers to text:

```
    For Each cell In ProductCode
        If cell.Value < 999999 Then
            cell.Value = "'" & cell.Text
        End If
    Next Cells
```

**Pre-pend** *(if that is the correct word)* a single quote to the visible value.  This assumes that `cell` is a Range variable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will work. I tried that, but was using cell.values instead of text, because I'm a dummy.

Answer (score 0):

With

> `If cells.Value < 999999 Then`

Excel will force the blanks to be `0` which is less than 999999 and the `CDec(cells)` returns `0`

If you want to skip the blanks add that check to the IF

```
If cells.Value < 999999 and cells <> "" Then
```